# Discord welcome dm embed?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to figure out how to turn this code into an embed that DM's a user upon arrival of the discord server.

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    member.send('BRUH')
       .catch(console.error);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

To create and send an embed:

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

member.send(exampleEmbed);
```

#### Links you should take a look at:

- [Disord.js Guide: Embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)